# Updating tabulator-tables 5.4.4 to 5.5.0 leads to "Event Target Lookup Error"

Tags: tabulator

After updating tabulator-tables from version 5.4.4 to 5.5.0 I get several errors (in an angular (16) environment):

```
Event Target Lookup Error - The row this cell is attached to cannot be found, has the table been reinitialized without being destroyed first.
```

It seems the the error occurs when the mouse pointers "hovers" over the row/cell. When I go back to version 5.4. the error goes away.

Does anybody knows what going on?

The environment to "reproduce" the error is rather difficult to establish, so I have currently no stackblitz etc.